# Data Extension synchronous Rest API where there are only primary keys

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, dataextensions

I have a data extension with 2 fields/attributes. These 2 fields are string types  and primary keys.
According to documentation the request body for synchronous APIs request should be:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postDataExtensionRowsetByKey.htm

Here is my request body:

```
[{
    "keys": {
        "My Key 1": "key value 1",
        "My Key 2": "key value 2"
    },
    "values":{}
}]
```

Result:

```
{
"message": "Unable to save rows for data extension ID d1c527ab-7f03-e911-8b2d-9c8e9920e9fc",
"errorcode": 10006,
"documentation": ""
}
```

Comment: Will your DE contain more fields or is will it always contain 2 keys that are primary keys? If you don't intend to extend it, do they even need to be primary keys?

Comment: I need only 2 and they must be primary keys.

Comment: If extend my Data Extension with one more field that is not primary key and call request where body also includes this field but in the values object - it works well. There is another way is to switch from sync request async.

Comment: Yes, I tried to do the same and adding another column seemed like the only option to solve this. It's as if the API endpoint requires a column that's not a primary key column.

Comment: I guess that is Salesforce bug, especially when it's possible through async requests.

Answer (score 0):

After review and a few tests I must say that is a Salesforce bug.
As temporary workaround until it's not fixed it requires adding at least one attribute to Data Extension that is not primary key and include its to the request body:

```
[{
"keys": {
    "My Key 1": "key value 1",
    "My Key 2": "key value 2"
},
"values":{
  "Temp Field": ""
}}]
```